# highlight items in recyclerview android

Tags: android-recyclerview

I am trying to select items in recylerview. When I click an item, a checkbox appears on that item and it is highlighted. But the problem is that when I scroll, the item which is highlighted goes to its original color but the checkbox image remains as it should. Why the highlighted color is gone but the image remains after scrolling, I want the items to keep their state after scrolling.

```
public static List<Model> item = new ArrayList<Model>()
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int
            position) {
        holder.bind(item.get(position));

               //

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check);

            public void bind(Model model) {

            if (model.isChecked()){
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                model.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                model.setChecked(false);
            }
        
              itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                        Model s = item.get(getAdapterPosition());
                        if (!selectList.contains(s)){
                            selectList.add(s);
                            model.setChecked(true);
                        } else {
                            selectList.remove(s);
                            model.setChecked(false);

                        }
                        notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                    }
            });

public class Model {
 
  private boolean isChecked = false;

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isChecked = checked;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't manually change the design in the onclick listener, just update your model (as you are already doing: model.setchecked(...) depending on state)

Then call Adapter.notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition())

This will force the adapter to reload the item, calling onBindViewHolder, where the design should be updated properly

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                    Model s = item.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    if (!selectList.contains(s)){
                        selectList.add(s);                           
                        model.setChecked(true);                            

                    } else {
                        selectList.remove(s);                            
                        model.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition())

                }
```

In the above example, replace "adapter" with a reference to your recylerview adapter

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `Don't manually change the design in the onclick listener` is confusing. I tried removing `model.setChecked` from onclick but then even check image disappears after scrolling. If you could explain that with bit of code that would be very helpful.

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully make it a bit more clear

Comment: thanks your answer but I still have not been able to solve this. I made the change in my code above and when I click, the item does not highlight. However the check image works fine as it should. If you could take a look at that, I would be very grateful to you.

Comment: Do you have your code in some public git repo? Then i could try it out myself. Otherwise i would just advise you to watch a few tutoriols on recyclerview until you get a better understanding of it.